# QtQuick anchoring syntax confusion

Tags: qt, user-interface, syntax, qml, qtquick2

As we [know](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html), anchoring is done like this:

```
anchors.left: rect1.right
```

... where `rect1` is an object deriving from `Item`.

But the [`Item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) QML type doesn't have a `right` property. So how does this anchoring syntax work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the `Item` QML type doesn't have a `right` property

[It does](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitem.h#n123). The documentation for e.g. [`anchors.right`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#anchors.right-prop) links to [Positioning with Anchors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html), which says:

> In addition to the more traditional Grid, Row, and Column, Qt Quick also provides a way to layout items using the concept of anchors. Each item can be thought of as having a set of 7 invisible "anchor lines": left, horizontalCenter, right, top, verticalCenter, baseline, and bottom.

I'm not entirely certain why they're not documented like regular properties, though.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitem.h) and then [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitem_p.h) header file. `anchors.left` for example is a read-only property of type `QQuickAnchorLine`.
See [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickanchors_p.h) and [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickanchors_p_p.h) headers. There is where you can see how it works.